# gulp task starts but does not end

Tags: gulp

I have the next files structure:

```
src/
    themes/
        default/
            1.png
            2.png
        oneMoreTheme/
            3.png
            4.png
dist
    themes/
        default/
        oneMoreTheme/
```

and the next gulpfile:

```
  'use strict';

  var gulp = require('gulp'),
    _ = require('lodash'),
    plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

  gulp.task('images', function () {
    var streams = {},
      themes = [
        'default',
        'oneMoreTheme'
      ];

    streams.themesImages = [];

    _.forEach(themes, function(theme) {
      streams.themesImages.push(gulp.src('src/themes/' + theme + '/*.*')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/themes/' + theme + '/')));
    });

    streams.allThemeImages = plugins.merge(streams.themesImages);

    return streams.allThemeImages;
  });
```

I can not understand two things:
1) Why do I see in console the next text when task "images" starts:

```
"D:\home\projects\storyBook>gulp images
[15:05:23] Using gulpfile D:\home\projects\storyBook\gulpfile.js
[15:05:23] Starting 'images'..."
```

But when task is finished I do NOT see the next text:

```
"[12:13:56] Finished 'images' after 5.72 s"
```

Why do not I get this text? I do streams merge and then return merged stream to have synchronous task. Maybe I do something wrong?

2) If I add one code line to my privous code:

```
streams.allThemeImages = plugins.merge(streams.themesImages);
return streams.allThemeImages.pipe(gulp.dest('temp/')); // HERE IS NEW CODE LINE
```

I expect that in temp folder I'll have the next images:
temp/
    1.png
    2.png
    3.png
    4.png
Because I merged streams, first one contains 1.png and 2.png images and second one contains 3.png and 4.png. But in reality I get the next files:
temp/
    1.png
    2.png
What is wrong?

Comment: other than being a tad complicated it works pretty well... this ain't a Gulpfile, though. Is it some splitted up file? How to you read it in your original Gulpfile?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not understand what you meant. I found out that when I use gulp-merge plugin then I have these two problems, but If I use merge2 plugin instead of gulp-merge then I have not these problems! But I want to know why I have problems when I use gulp-merge plugin.

Comment: I was just curious about your `module.exports` statement, I didn't quite catch on to it. `gulp-merge` is btw. not a real gulp plugin (it does not transform files) and very broken, since it doesn't use streams but buffers. Don't use it, use `merge2` or `event-stream` instead

Comment: Btw. `gulp-merge` is not supported anymore. The maintainer of this project now develops actively on `merge2`. Use gulp plugins only if: 1. they transform files (not streams!) and 2. It changes files inside the stream between start and end. as seen in http://fettblog.eu/gulp-recipes-part-2/

Comment: Oh, sorry about this "module.exports", I just made example gulpfile and made it from my real gulpfile which uses wrench.readdirSyncRecursive(options.gulpTasks).map(function(file) {
  require(options.gulpTasks + file)(options);
});